# NodeJS send an email from a local SMTP server

Tags: node.js, email

So I've been making an app that should send verification e-mails, but I don't know how to approach it. I've seen people use Gmail with a combination of `nodemailer` to send messages, but I don't want to be dependent on Google.

I've seen the package `smtp-server` that will make a simple smtp server, but so far I've gotten it receiving emails and receiving emails from itself, so to speak, but can't send emails from my local SMTP server to, let's say, Gmail or Yahoo.

So far my code looks something like this:

```js
const smtpServer = require('smtp-server');
const mailparser = require('mailparser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const a = new smtpServer.SMTPServer({
    onData(stream, session, callback) {
        mailparser.simpleParser(stream, (err, main) => {
            console.log("An email was received:");
            console.log("    From: " + main.from.text);
            console.log("    To: " + main.to.text);
            console.log("    Text: " + main.text);
            callback(err);
        });
    },
    onAuth: function (auth, session, callback) {
        callback(null, { user: auth });
    },
    disabledCommands: ['AUTH']
});
a.listen(587, '192.168.....');

nodemailer
    .createTransport( {
        host: "My public ip",
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: "username",
            pass: "password"
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    })
    .sendMail({
        from: '"Verification" <verification@test.com>',
        to: 'my.email@gmail.com',
        html: `Test`,
        headers: {
        }
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Problem is, right now my server receives the message I sent, not google's. I know I'm doing something wrong, but how do I fix it?

Comment: Sadly, it's pretty hard to run your own mail server. See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/why-you-may-not-want-to-run-your-own-mail-server for some of the challenges involved.

Comment: @Julia I really don't need anything, except the ability to send emails to other servers

Comment: I think it’d be much easier to use an API for that.

Comment: Have you verified that you are able to make an outbound connection from your computer to any of the google mail servers? Many ISP's block smtp outbound traffic.

Comment: Off of your `.sendMail()` add a `.then(info => console.log(info)` to see what the result of sending your email is.